# Extension refused to load the font in manifest.json.1

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

Following is my *manifest.json*:

```json
{
  "name": "gitvote",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "for git vote",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://github.com/*",
    "https://gitlab.com/*",
    "storage"
  ],
  "optional_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

When I run it as a chrome extension, an error:

```
'Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAJd6ABIAAAABdegAAAAAAACWIAAAAVoAAAKDAAAAA…SYUnjpYfcSDw49uhYFPVe8dHZcYGS7Cfk4MMJ7zwjznvGw3PMA2Oo6+tf/wpSdPlSR/ADe7uPx' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src assets-cdn.github.com".' in manifest.json.1 occurs.
```

I don't understand why the error occurs in manifest.json.1.

Thank you.

Comment: The error shows github's CSP for fonts allows only their own assets-cdn. Try adding `; font-src data:` to CSP in your manifest (or `'unsafe-inline'` instead of `data:`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I added font-src like this:  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'; font-src data:".
However, the same error also occurred.

Comment: I'm sorry, I disabled my extension as a test and found that the error didn't occur due to my extension.
Thank you for your help!!